# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization get upgraded to 5.0 in .NET Core 3.1 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I am struggling with a .NET Core 3.1 project. Each time I build it I get:

```
  CodingConnected.YAVC.ClientApi.csproj: [NU1601] Dependency specified was Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization (>= 3.1.14) but ended up with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization 5.0.5.
```

This is problematic, because if I run the project (an API) I get:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'configure')
```

This is due to the fact that the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization is upgraded to 5.0.5, which is incompatible with .NET Core 3.1.

I seem to be unable to permanently downgrade this dependency. The project uses Paket for dependency management.

Any ideas on what might be the cause of this are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried to specify/install 3.1.x version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization` ?

Comment: Have you seen that Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization^5.0.5 has dependency to net5.0? but you want to use it on net core 3.1

Comment: Yes, it is clear that the 5.x version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization` is not compatible with .NET Core 3.1. The project actually is netcoreapp 3.1, and I tried downgrading the package as well as specifying version 3.1.14 manually. Just upon build, the system uses 5.0.5 instead. Might this have to do with other dependencies in the project?

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error: the problem was a dependency in another package, namely `NSwag.AspNetCore`, which is at version 13.10.9 for some days. Reverting back to 13.10.8 solved the issue.